# Jquery - Check Nodes for button behavior

Tags: jquery, button, nodes, behavior

I am currently doing a wiziwig. I have a difficulty interacting with the bold button.
When I select a part of text. I would like the bold button to be in focus if the text contains bold. In fact if the text contains bold, this will reactivate the button.

I imagine to do it.

```
$(Visual#').Mouseup(function () {
         Var test = getSelection();
}
```

[image]

I retrieve the object to check if the node `strong` exists. The condition activates focus on the button.

Sorry for my English i'm French ^^

thx

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, and it seems that you want us to write code for you, which is not what StackOverflow is intended for. If you do have a question regarding you code, then please do share it with us, and we'll try to figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**Finally i did this and and it seems to work**

(function () {

```
document.getElementById('visuel')
    .addEventListener('contextmenu', rightClickHandler, false);

function rightClickHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var target = event.target;
    console.log(target);
    if(!target){
        return false;
    }
    switch (target.nodeName.toUpperCase()) {
        case 'STRONG':
            $('.bold').addClass('focus');
            break;
        case 'EM':
            $('.italic').addClass('focus');
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

})();